# addClass problem in jquery with (html) page

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a class to li , on click event, but whenever I do that it does add class for a moment then load the page, I have used the following code.

```
$('.navLi').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

I wish to selected tab on navigator Li .How I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the default action:

```
$('.navLi').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

See [the API](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault).

Answer (score 0):

just return false to disable the default behaviour

```
$('.navLi').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
return false;
});
```

Edit: oh .. hold on, when you click an li it loads the page? is there a link in the li?